# How Can I fill Select created in Modal Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Here is my trying:

```
$('#modalSetComplain').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {               
                FillinputComplaintype2();               
            });
```

This is function which will fill the Select dynamically

```
 function FillinputComplaintype2() {
            var options = $("#inputComplaintype2");
            $.each( datelist  , function (val, text) {
                options.append($("<option />").val(text.Name).text(text.Id));
            });
        }
```

and this is my modal

```
   <div class="modal modal-flex " id="modalSetComplain">
        <div class="modal-dialog" style="min-width: 900px; max-width:1000px;width:auto">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">&nbsp;</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">


                    <div class="form-horizontal" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inptComplaintitle" style="width:15%"><strong> </strong></label>
                         <input type="text" name="inptComplaintitle" class="form-control" id="inptComplaintitle" style="width:60%"/>
                        </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputComplaintype2" style="width:15%"><strong> </strong></label>
                          <select class="form-control" id="inputComplaintype2"  style="width:60%"></select>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="SaveComplains();" class="btn btn-green ladda-button">

                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My modal Successfully appeared but how can I fill `id="inputComplaintype2"`
daynamically on modal load ?
also

```
$('#modalSetComplain').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
```

didn't fire its event even it located in document.ready

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `shown` event (after the modal has appeared) rather than the `show` event.

```
$('#modalSetComplain').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {               
                FillinputComplaintype2();               
            });
```